# Highcharts tooltips disappearing in tabbed layout

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, highcharts

I  have a bunch of highcharts charts all over my website.
If they are all put on the same tab they all load the legend and the tooltips correctly.
But if they are on different tabs the tooltips disappear completely and the legends do not have the correct formatting with shadow and such. No errors show in the console for anything and I do not get an error in my code.

I am also using highcharts.net so all my code to create the charts are in c#.

Here is the image of the working charts on the first tab.
[image]

you see it looks and works perfectly fine.

Then you switch tabs and go check another chart and they are like this. Where the legends are broken and the tooltips do not work.
[image]

It really doesn't make much sense. Especially because I am loading each chart separately thru an ajax call. Why would they work on one tab and break on the other.

Really any help would be great I've tried many things. Taking out my custom javascript in the charts. Changing the legends and tooltips. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: If your legend border is made through css (i.e., in [styled mode](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css) it's possible in the second case the relevant style snippet or css file link is missing or wrong. It's unlikely anyone can give you a solution unless you post your code.

Comment: Hard to say without a source code. I would guess that you are using different css classes (For Lengend and Title) for first and second chart.